# Swift 3 'encode' produces 'Void' (aka '()'), not the expected contextual result type XYZ?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

At the moment, I'm writing the 'encode'() for my 'Note' object, in preparation for their being serialised. I have looked high and low for tutorials on how to serialise in Swift 3.0, and for this error message, but to no avail.

This code from an unrelated, previous project (converted from Swift 2.2 to 3.0), works absolutely fine:

```
//Serialise the object.

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        aCoder.encodeCInt(personIDNumber, forKey: "personIDNumber")
        aCoder.encode(staffName, forKey: "staffName")
        aCoder.encode(userName, forKey: "userName")
        aCoder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
    }
```

However, if I attempt to do the same in my current project (which was started in Swift 3.0):

```
public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) 
{
    noteText = aCoder.encode(noteText, forKey: "noteText")
}
```

This is the error that occurs:

```
'encode' produces 'Void' (aka '()'), not the expected contextual result type String? ***Bizzarely, this also causes every 'encode' function that's available with NSCoder-type objects to be struck-through, as though deprecated, which obviously isn't true***.
```

My 'decode'() is as follows, and the compiler is happy with it:

```
required public init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        noteText = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:  "noteText") as! String?
    }
```

So, what I'm after is this:

• A set of clear steps on how to fix this error (simply because I'm still new to Swift, and am absolutely stumped by this message, and for people who come after me).

• An explanation of why this is occurring, and why (if possible), my 'decode()' is perfectly acceptable in both the cases I've given, but 'encode()'

Any help is gratefully received and thanked for in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noteText`, a property of the class `encode(with:)` belongs to (`Note`?), is of a given type, say `XYZ`. The `encode(, forKey:)` method(s) of `aCoder` (of type `NSCoder`), however, is a (are) *non-returning function*, [with signatures looking like](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder):

> ```
> func encode(_ realv: Double, 
>      forKey key: String)
> ```

Note the lack of an explicit return type of this method. It does *not* return a value of type `XYZ` such as you expect, and as you attempt to assign the result of the call to `encode(_:forKey:)` to a property (`noteText`), you will get the expected type mismatch, as `noteText` is not of type `Void` (empty tuple, `()`), which is the default return of functions with no return type specified.

I don't know what you want to achieve here, but you cannot assign the return of the `encode(_:forKey:)` call to any kind of property (except a useless property of type `()`), so removing this assignment will rid you of the error message of the question title.

```
// change this
noteText = aCoder.encode(noteText, forKey: "noteText")

// into
aCoder.encode(noteText, forKey: "noteText")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! In answer to your question, what I wanted to do was encode this property into a binary file as part of a Note object. In Swift 2.2, as far as I remember, you could do what I had initially done.

Comment: @Paul happy to help.